# Google Dataflow vs Tensorflow vs Plain Python: Data Mining and Data Preparation

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to download JSON from an API and then prepare CSVs for usage on Machine Learning.

Which is the best option? Dataflow? Tensorflow?

I am not sure about Dataflow as there is a URL Fetching operation? 
Does Tensorflow fit for data preparation?

Comment: How much data? Is this something that is run continuously or off a schedule (hourly/daily/...) or adhoc? Do you care if it runs on your machine or is it important for it to run on a VM somewhere in the cloud?

Comment: Needs to run on a VM. I am thinking to run it scheduled.